# Circumventing Subnet Security

Tags: subnet

My understanding is that subnets are contractual agreements between hosts on a network. Assuming all hosts are connected on layer two, subnets would provide no insulation from an attacker attempting to pivot between machines.

Is this correct? If so, are subnets only security use segregating external traffic to hardened machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the same is true for real networks. You can have "supernetworks" combining multiple old class c and switch between them at will. It has never been meant as a security platform - there is no security. It is way to express routing.